# Ошибка соединения с БД Postgresql PyCharm

Tags: postgresql, pycharm, docker-compose

Не могу подключиться к БД, хотя я уверен на 100% что все данные правильные, я скачал проект с git на другой пк, и всё работает и подключается, но у меня на ноутбуке возникает такая ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Windows 10, Home,
PyCharm Pro 2021.1.1

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: diploma_container
    restart: always
    command: ./commands/start_server_${MODE}.sh
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${WSGI_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - .\src:/srv/project/src
      - .\commands:/srv/project/commands
      - .\src\media:/srv/project/media
      - static_content:/var/www/diploma
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.${MODE}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - redis

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
#    environment:
#      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    volumes:
      - .\nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_content:/var/www/diploma
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - backend

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
#    ports:
#      - 8181:15672
    env_file: .env
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis
    env_file: .env
    restart: always

  redis-commander:
    container_name: redis-commander
    hostname: redis-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
    - REDIS_HOSTS=redis
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"

  celery:
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    command: ./commands/start_celery.sh
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.${MODE}
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/project/src
      - ./commands:/srv/project/commands

  celerybeat:
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    container_name: celerybeat
    command: ./commands/start_celerybeat.sh
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - celery
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.${MODE}
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/project/src
      - ./commands:/srv/project/commands


volumes:
  pg_data: {}
  static_content: {}
```

Создание БД и пользователя:

```
CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE admin SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE admin SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE admin SET timezone TO 'UTC';

CREATE DATABASE test;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO admin;

ALTER USER admin CREATEDB;
```

Comment: Может сервер не включен, на линуксе это можно сделать командой ```service postgresql start```

Comment: @v1nc3nt_0'ne1ll включен

Comment: Postgres установлен локально или удаленно?

Comment: @v1nc3nt_0'ne1ll на докере

Comment: Тогда не знаток, я слышал что там с докером проблемы большые на windows

Comment: @v1nc3nt_0'ne1ll понял, спасибо

Comment: @RomanKonoval добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не наблюдаю у Вас в `docker-compose` задания пользователя. Для этого надо задать `POSTGRES_USER`. Либо явно либо в ваше окружение, в данном случае должен быть указан в файле `.env`. По умолчанию пользователь `postgres` от него Вы и будете подключаться, в случае если не заданы пользователи.

Если Вы все таки задали пользователя и уверены в правильности, то советую проделать следующее:

1. Зайти внутрь контейнера
   `docker exec -it <имя контейнера postgres> bash`
2. подключиться к БД
   `psql -U postgres`
3. Посмотреть пользователей.
   `\du`

Дальше в зависимости от результата, если вашего юзера нет, значит Вы его не правильно задали/что то еще, если есть то проверяйте пароль/pg_hba файл на предмет доступа/ и тд.

**UPDATE**

На втором скрине видно что `project encoding = windows-1251` при этом глобальная - `UTF-8` так понимаю linux на текущей машине, если другой компьютер с виндой "проект с git на другой пк, и всё работает и подключается", то ответ очевиден). Либо перед созданием поменять кодировку проекта, либо заранее задать переменную `PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8` для windows само собой другую - это изменит стандартную кодировку системы.

По поводу

```
ALTER ROLE admin SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
```

Если Вы подключаетесь после этого из терминала для проверки, то этот прием не поможет. Из [документации](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/12/app-psql).

> Если и стандартный ввод, и стандартный вывод являются терминалом, то psql установит кодировку клиента в «auto», и подходящая клиентская кодировка будет определяться из локальных установок (переменная окружения LC_CTYPE в Unix). Если это работает не так, как ожидалось, кодировку клиента можно изменить, установив переменную окружения PGCLIENTENCODING.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, пользователь и admin и postgres есть, я смог подключиться через postgres но admin не пропускает, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Добавил код создания БД и пользователя в вопрос

Comment: А логи pg не смотрели ? так же зайти в контейнер и в `pgdata/logs`.
Еще вопрос - какая ОС на ноутбуке. Скорее всего проблема с кодировкой пароля. Дополню ответ по кодировке.